# Correcting ReturnNumber

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr

I am trying to run [track_sensor()](https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/track_sensor.html) and am receiving the following error:

```
track_sensor(ctg, Roussel2020(), thin_pulse_with_time = 0, multi_pulse = T)
#> Processing [========>-----------------------------------]  20% (4/20) eta: 20mAn error occurred when processing the chunk 4. Try to load this chunk with:
#>  chunk <- readRDS("/tmp/RtmpEBHRvU/chunk4.rds")
#>  las <- readLAS(chunk)
#> After keeping only first and last returns of multiple returns pulses, 8 pulses still have more than 2 points. This dataset is corrupted and gpstime is likely to be invalid.
```

After investigating I am finding the following kinds of problematic pulses:

```r
chunk <- readRDS("/tmp/RtmpEBHRvU/chunk4.rds")
las <- readLAS(chunk)
las@data[gpstime == 84410683.44697999954224]
#>                          X                       Y                       Z
#> 1: 552000.4799999999813735 4561465.839999999850988 374.7699999999999818101
#> 2: 552005.1900000000605360 4561404.139999999664724 381.9800000000000181899
#> 3: 552001.1600000000325963 4561404.379999999888241 366.8000000000000113687
#>                    gpstime ReturnNumber NumberOfReturns ScanAngleRank UserData
#> 1: 84410683.44697999954224            1               3           -17        0
#> 2: 84410683.44697999954224            1               3           -17        0
#> 3: 84410683.44697999954224            2               3           -17        0
#>    PointSourceID buffer  flag problem
#> 1:          3345      1 FALSE    TRUE
#> 2:          3345      1 FALSE    TRUE
#> 3:          3345      1 FALSE      NA
las@data[gpstime == 84410683.53884577751160]
#>                          X                       Y                       Z
#> 1: 552000.0799999999580905 4561473.350000000558794 376.0500000000000113687
#> 2: 552004.7900000000372529 4561411.690000000409782 383.3899999999999863576
#> 3: 552002.4300000000512227 4561411.839999999850988 374.4900000000000090949
#>                   gpstime ReturnNumber NumberOfReturns ScanAngleRank UserData
#> 1: 84410683.5388457775116            1               3           -17        0
#> 2: 84410683.5388457775116            1               3           -17        0
#> 3: 84410683.5388457775116            2               3           -17        0
#>    PointSourceID buffer  flag
#> 1:          3345      1 FALSE
#> 2:          3345      1 FALSE
#> 3:          3345      1 FALSE
```

This looks like a clear case of mislabeled `ReturnNumber`. Would it be ok to correct `ReturnNumber` myself? I would likely order them by `Z` within each `gpstime` group (pulse). The other option would be to identify these pulses ahead of time and filter them out, though I'm not sure which option is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your points are not spatially aligned meaning they are not from the same pulse.

```r
d = read.table(text = "
 X Y Z
552000.08 4561473.35 376.05
552004.8 4561411.69 383.39
552002.43 4561411.84 374.50
", header = T)

library(lidR)
las = LAS(d)
plot(las, size = 3, axis = T)
```

So the problem is not a problem of mislabelling of `ReturnNumber`. Maybe a mislabelling of `UserData`. But `ScanAngle` are equal while points seem to a be at very different location. Some points look incorrect.

Anyway you can manually modify an attribute if you are sure of what you are doing

```r
las$UserData[1] = 1L
```

Comment: Very interesting...Thanks for pointing this out! I think I'd rather flag and filter these points.